# Keep element on top of overlay on hover fabric js

Tags: fabricjs

I am trying to achieve something like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MACNV.png)

i have set overlayColor but when i hover on an object on the canvas its still behind overlay. I have set bringToFront on the object with no luck. Kindly assist

Comment: `overlayColor` and `backgroundOverlay` are on top of all canvas objects.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. Is there a hack that can achieve something like that ? I am trying to achieve like in this jquery plugin [link](https://www.jqueryscript.net/demo/jQuery-Plugin-To-Set-Focus-On-Any-DOM-Element-Focusable/# )

Comment: yes..use a rectangle with a fill color instead of overlayColor

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. i have added an image to the canvas. On hovering on an object, i reduce the opacity of the other objects. The problem is when i remove hover, the objects are not returning to their original state until i click the canvas. Any ideas ?